# Combine 2 rows into one dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I try to combine two rows in dataframe into one

```
              ID           Value1         Value2    
0             ID_1           NaN            2           
1             ID_2           NaN            7    
2             ID_1           5             NaN   
3             ID_2           8             NaN
```

The result should be the following

```
              ID           Value1         Value2    
1             ID_1           5              2     
2             ID_2           8              7
```

Is it possible with a method of dataframe ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this particular case you can also use `groupby()`:

```
df = df.groupby('ID')['Value1','Value2'].sum().reset_index()
```

Answer (score 1):

via `stack/unstack`

```
df = df.set_index('ID').stack().unstack().reset_index()
```

Output:

```
     ID  Value1  Value2
0  ID_1     5.0     2.0
1  ID_2     8.0     7.0
```

Comment: It's not working, I have this error ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape

Answer (score 1):

Use `set_index()` **,** `apply()` method and `sorted()` method:

```
newdf=df.set_index('ID').apply(lambda x : sorted(x,key=pd.isnull))
```

Finally use boolean masking and `isna()` method:

```
newdf=newdf[~newdf.isna().all(1)]
```

Now If you print `newdf` you will get your desired output:

```
       Value1   Value2
ID      
ID_1    5.0     2.0
ID_2    8.0     7.0
```

If needed use `reset_index()` method:

```
newdf=newdf.reset_index()
```

Output of above code:

```
    ID      Value1  Value2
0   ID_1    5.0     2.0
1   ID_2    8.0     7.0
```

Comment: If there are unequal amounts of NAN's in value1/value2 will it not drop all after sorting?

Comment: you are right....updated answer....btw thanks for noticing this @Nk03 **:)**